# Using "proxies" with git

Tags: git, ssh

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to `ssh` from my machine `X` to a machine `Y`, do a `git pull` over there and then retrieve the compiled code so I can see where we're at.

I would like to use `git` directly on `X`, but I can't because I pull code from a local network that `Y` belongs to. Is there a way to somehow use `X` as a proxy, so I could use git directly on my machine and save myself a lot of hassle?

(I'm using a Linux distribution, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

If you have sshd running on `Y` (since you can `ssh` on `Y` and perform operations), you can:

- install `git` on `X`
- `git clone ssh://user@Y:/path/to/repo/on/Y`

That way, you get a clone of `Y` repo directly on `X`, make modifications and can push back to `Y` repo (`origin`) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ssh's proxy feature.  For instance, I have (names obscured to protect the guilty :-) ):

```
# tunneling
Host *.secure2.com
    ProxyCommand ssh secure1.local.com 'conn %h %p'
```

where "conn" is a command I have that does a connection to the target host/port pair.  You can use the `nc` command if you have that.  See the `ssh_config` man page (normally in section 5).

Answer (score 1):

I would just forward a local port to machine Y when you ssh into machine X:

```
ssh -L2022:Y:22 yourself@Y
```

Now while your ssh session exists you can use another local shell and run ssh commands against machine Y:

```
git clone ssh://yourself@localhost:2022/repos/Yrepo repo_from_Y
```

Or of course, having cloned/pulled from Y to X you can clone/pull from X to your local machine  making X be a proxying intermediate. If you make the clone on X be a bare mirror of Y you could add a cron job to keep it up to date. Using a local forwarding port is simplest really and very flexible.